# change default settings for "Require Password Reset" in User Manager

Tags: user

I want to make the default setting for Require Password Reset in the user manager > new user creation to yes instead of no. is this possible? where would i go about it? is there an admin view I could override?

Answer (score 1):

https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/miscellaneous/form-xml-override/

will let you then create an override on a model/forms/ .xml file in the administration (or frontend). it rocks.